# Name of a Scif-Fi/Fantasy book where space rescuers encounter vampires aboard a crashed ship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, vampire

I've been trying to figure this one out for years. I read a book as a teenager (so around 15-20 years ago), where a ship lands to assist another ship or a colony who have succumbed to a sickness/plague. The twist of the story is the other ship is full of vampires, who have lured the rescuers there in order to convert them/feed on them. The planet they were rescuing from *may* have been Mars.

I'd much like to read the story again, but I've never been able to find the book at my parents house, and have completely forgotten the author.

Answer (score 10):

While it isn't a landing, the book titled "[The Space Vampires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Vampires)" has a derelict spacecraft that is discovered in a near asteroid belt. They discover 3 people in suspended animation who are acutally energy vampires that get loose on Earth, and the book was the basis for the movie "Lifeforce", of the light emitting genitalia genre.

Comment: *Light emitting genitalia*? Do I want to know?

Comment: http://johnrieber.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/lifeforce-movie-nudity1.jpg

Comment: The beginning of the synopsis seems familiar (3 vampires in suspended animation), but I don't remember them going back to Earth - maybe I'll have to find a copy and read it first! (Also - you'd think I'd have already come across it if it was called "The Space Vampires"! I'll be kicking myself if it's that much of an oversight.)

Comment: @Jersey LifeForce is definitely worth catching some time

Comment: @sHtev - I agree, it's not the best fit, but it's about the only thing that I could find that even came close.

Comment: Well, I've ordered a copy from amazon, so hopefully it will jog my memory at least, thanks for the (in hindsight, obvious) pointer!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [*Planet of the Vampires*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Vampires), a 1965 Italian/Spanish science fiction horror film. It starred Barry Sullivan and Norma Bengell.

> The story follows the horrific experiences of the crew members of two giant spaceships that have crash landed on a forbidding, unexplored planet. The disembodied inhabitants of the world possess the bodies of the crew who died during the crash, and use the animated corpses to stalk and kill the remaining survivors.

....

> Markary and his crew rush to the Galliott to retrieve the Meteor Rejector. They are successful, and manage to place explosives in the ship. During a struggle with the Aurans, Dr. Karan (Fernando Villeña) and Tiona are killed. Markary and Sanya return to the Argos and manage to escape as the Galliott is destroyed. After takeoff, however, they reveal themselves to be possessed by Aurans. They ask Wes, the last survivor, to join them. Wes refuses and tries to sabotage the Meteor Rejector, but fatally electrocutes himself while doing so. Because the device has been broken beyond repair, Markary and Sanya decide to change course for a nearby planet...Earth.